# Is there a way to let Emacs' regexp based commands such `query-replace-regexp` use Perl regexp?

Tags: emacs, regex

Is there a way to let Emacs' regexp based commands such `query-replace-regexp` use Perl regexp?

I am hoping there is some reasonably simple way to achieve this, for example, by adding code in `.emacs`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, no, there isn't.  Almost all features of Perl regular expressions are available, though; see the info manual, under `Top > Search > Regexps` for details on what the Emacs version of the same syntax is.